# Problem exploiting buffer overflow

Tags: buffer-overflow, c

I have the following program in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void some_function(char * name) {
   char buf[128];
   strcpy(buf, "The next step is... ");
   strcat(buf, name);
   strcat(buf, ".");
   puts(buf);
}
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   if (argc < 2)
      puts("Please enter a command line parameter.");
   else
      some_function(argv[1]);
   return 0;
}
```

And this is my program to exploit the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char shellcode[] = "shellcode + \x30\xf3\xff\bf";

int main() {
   int i;
   //128 buffer length, 20 string length, 4 oldEBP, 4 return address
   for (i=0; i<128-20-strlen(shellcode)+4+4; i++) printf("\x90");
   printf("%s", shellcode);
   return 0;
}
```

The vulnerable program is compiled as follows:

```
gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -m32 -fno-pie -g -o vuln vuln.c
```

I get the return address from gdb:

```
(gdb) x/xb buf
0xbffff330:     0x88
```

I get a segmentation fault and I wonder if I miss an address to overwrite or what I'm doing wrong.

It's running on a 32 bit Ubuntu 10.04 VM.